# Ckan add extra field to user

Tags: ckan

I've been succesful adding extra fields to packages and resources(through the provided plugins) but I don't know how to add an extra fields to users. I'd like to upload an image to replace the gravatar one. I couldn't find a way to modify the user schema without touching the core code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately CKAN's user object does not have extra fields as other objects do. So there is no flexibility on the fields stored against the user.

This is a long wanted feature by several projects and waits for someone to implement it in CKAN - see: https://github.com/ckan/ideas-and-roadmap/issues/16 - (hint, hint).